# How to change the ownership of the installed program to my account?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, ownership

For some reason I need to change ownership from EVERYONE to just my account. Is it possible or do I need to reinstall the program?

System: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a setting within the application to do this (not common), the easiest way to fix this is to uninstall, restart the computer (for good measure) and re-install the application